# Выводятся ???? вместо русcких букв в PHP

Tags: php, кодировка, utf-8

Имеем базу данных MySQL с кодировкой utf8_general_ci

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же, имеем PHP файл который берёт данные из базы (кодировка UTF-8)

```html
<?php
header('Content-type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
$connection = mysql_connect( 'localhost', '***', '***' );
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf-8');
mysql_set_charset("UTF-8", $connection);
mysql_select_db( '***' );
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM shell' ); 
?>
<shell>
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<message>
    <id><?php echo( htmlentities( $row['id'] ) ) ?></id>
    <desc><?php echo( htmlentities( $row['description'] ) ) ?></desc>
    <date><?php echo( htmlentities( $row['date'] ) ) ?></date>
    <time><?php echo( htmlentities( $row['time'] ) ) ?></time>
</message>
<?php
}
mysql_free_result($result);
?>
</shell>
```

И в итоге, получаю вывод через браузер

```html
<shell>
<message>
<id>1</id>
<desc>???? ???????????? ??????</desc>
<date>123</date>
<time>233</time>
</message>
<message>
<id>2</id>
<desc>34234-1</desc>
<date>234234-2</date>
<time>234234-3</time>
</message>
<message>
<id>3</id>
<desc>12332</desc>
<date>32133</date>
<time>12334</time>
</message>
</shell>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне поставить правильную кодировку, что бы вместо знаков вопроса (???? ???????????? ??????) отображались русские буквы (Курс Классический массаж).
Копаюсь уже сутки - понять не могу.

И ещё, создал файл .htaccess с содержимым

```html
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Comment: а в базу данные были записаны в utf-8?

Comment: Прости, я в php новичёк. Не совсем понял твой вопрос.

Comment: Данные в базу кто-то записал. Он сделал это в какой-то кодировке. Эта кодировка могла быть не utf-8. Попробуй добавить запись сам и прочитать её же.

Comment: Я через базу данные и добавил, вручную

Comment: Может дело в `mysql_set_charset('utf8',$connection);`

Comment: Я и без него пробовал, все равно тоже самое

Comment: Там минус отсутствует в моём варианте. Попробуй так.

Comment: Как только убираю -, т.е, ставлю utf8, сразу возникает ошибка `This page contains the following errors:

error on line 4 at column 16: Entity 'ETH' not defined
error on line 4 at column 16: Encoding error
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.`

Comment: mysql_connect уже устарел, а в новых версиях php его совсем убрали по умолчанию. Я бы посоветовал попробовать сразу писать с mysqli или pdo - смысл в этом есть, и может даже проблема сама отпадет. Также стоит проверить, какая кодировка файла скрипта и других файлов, которые в нем используются через include / require - она должна быть utf-8 без BOM (обычный utf-8 имеет вначале файла служебные байты, из-за которых могут возникнуть проблемы).

Comment: Эти символы отображаются если через phpmyadmin вручную заполнять

Answer (score 1):

В самом редакторе поставьте utf-8 или ide не знаю что у вас, потом чистом виде библиотека mysql не поддерживается. Потом в кодировке дефис не прописывается + text/html лучше У вас как вариант можно использовать mysqli или pdo . Я использую pdo библиотеку сделайте такой код всё заработает DB

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASS', '');
define('DB_CHAR', 'utf8');

class DB
{
    protected static $instance = null;

    public function __construct() {}
    public function __clone() {}

    public static function instance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null)
        {
            $opt  = array(
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => TRUE,
            );
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME.';charset='.DB_CHAR;
            self::$instance = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS, $opt);
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array(self::instance(), $method), $args);
    }

    public static function run($sql, $args = [])
    {
        $stmt = self::instance()->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($args);
        return $stmt;
    }
}
?>
```

Далее вытаскиваем данные

```
$result = DB::run("SELECT * FROM shell");
foreach ($result as $row){
    echo"
<shell>
<message>
    <id>".$row['id']."</id>
    <desc>".$row['description']."></desc>
    <date>".$row['date']."></date>
    <time>".$row['time']."></time>
</message>
</shell>";
}
```

если будут ошибки пишите я проверил в версии 7.0

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66056/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim---c---php).

Answer (score 0):

Настоятельно не рекомендую использовать `mysql`.

> **Внимание**
>   Данная функция объявлена устаревшей в PHP 5.3.0, и, вместе с расширением MySQL, удалена PHP 7.0.0. Вместо нее используйте активно развивающиеся расширения MySQLi или PDO_MySQL.

Рекомендую использовать `mysqli`.

```
function con() {
    static $mysqli;
    if (!$mysqli) {
        mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
        $mysqli = new mysqli('хост', 'пользователь', 'пароль', 'имя базы данных');
        $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    }
    return $mysqli;
}

$con = con();
$shell = $con->query("SELECT * FROM shell");
// ..........
```

Не нужно делать `SET NAMES utf8` данная операция не работает с кодировкой соединения, нужно использовать метод `set_charset`.
Вообще нужно сделать базу, таблицы в `utf8`, и поля базы в `utf8_general_ci`, а также файлы с кодами, нужно конвертнуть в `UTF-8 (без BOM)` и в `.htaccess` прописать `AddDefaultCharset utf-8`, ну и в `index.php` (единую точку входа, где подключаются файлики, также задать заголовки).

```
header('Content-type:text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: этот ответ не имеет отношения к вопросую да и код сам по себе ужасен. Никогда не пиши кода, который заведомо вызовет ошибку.

Comment: С другой стороны, как рекомендация для других читателей вполне подойдет.